# Unclickable Element

Tags: java, android-intent, android-activity, kotlin

My screen doesn't respond. I mean the element was unclickable, even though I touch the button or textview elements. However, the previous page was clickable, I can touch the elements/area that will redirect me to the next page BUT on this page, I can't go forward again.

I'm using Kotlin and the IDE was Android Studio, got no error, and I can preview on my device, but still, the element was unclickable.

All codes have been uploaded to my Git:
https://gitlab.com/indranrachman/wishy-washy

Here if you want to see the page:

`MerchantServiceActivity.kt` - Unclickable

`activity_merchant_service.xml` - Unclickable

BUT the previous page was clickable, I can go forward to the Unclickable page but when I'm on the unclickable page I can't tap or touch anything. Here are the working ones:

`actvity_select_merchant.xml` - Clickable

`MerchantActivity.kt` - Clickable

Comment: Please add your relevant ("Unclickable") code here so we can get an idea of what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

call MerchantServiceActivity via intent and comment
  this line setContentView(R.layout.activity_merchant_service)

```
 layoutMerchant.setOnClickListener{
                //setContentView(R.layout.activity_merchant_service)
                val intent = Intent(this@MerchantActivity, MerchantServiceActivity::class.java)
                startActivity(intent)
            }

            toolbarSelectMerchant.setOnClickListener{
               //setContentView(R.layout.activity_home)
                onBackPressed()
            }
```

Comment: Thankyou bro! Solved! is this code working if i'm implement on the other elements like textview etc?

Comment: ya, it should be work. if you get any error then, please comment.